# Determine $\text{Vect}_k(S^n)$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\text{Vect}_k(X)$ denote the isomorphism classes of rank $k$ real vector bundles over smooth manifold $X$.

Is there a rule for determining $\text{Vect}_k(X)$ over reasonably nice manifolds?

Specifically, how to calculate $\text{Vect}_k(S^n)$, for $n$-spheres?

Answer (score 1):

As a general question, this is not an easy question to answer *at all*. It is studied in the field of "topological K-theory". Much of the work in this field is to answer an easier question of how many "stable equivalence classes" of rank $k$ vector bundles over $M$ there are, where two rank $k$ vector bundles $E_1 \mapsto M$, $E_2 \mapsto M$ are stably equivalent if there exists some trivial vector bundle $\epsilon \mapsto M$ of some rank such that $E_1 \oplus \epsilon$ and $E_2 \oplus \epsilon$ are isomorphic. And this easier question is still very hard to answer.

Still, though, there is a topological rule (which underlies the $K$-theory point of view). There is a "classifying space" for rank $k$ real vector bundles over $m$-dimensional manifolds $X$, which means that the isomorphism classes of such bundles are in 1--1 correspondence with homotopy classes of continuous maps from $X$ to the classifying space. This classifying space is the Grassmanian of $k$-planes in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some sufficiently high value of $n$; I forget how high $n$ has to be, but it has the form $n \ge C(k,m)$ for some constant depending only on $k,m$.

Your question about spheres then comes down to classifying homotopy classes of maps of spheres to the Grassmanian. This converts your question about spheres into a question of homotopy theory, namely computation of homotopy groups of Grassmanians, which makes algebraic topologists happy.

A good resource for all of this is the book "Characteristic Classes" by Milnor and Stasheff, and some of the more advanced books on manifolds such as "Differential Topology" by Hirsch.

Comment: To add to the reference list, the always pocketbook friendly "Vector Bundles and K-theory" by Hatcher, available at his website, is a nice resource.